# 32-bit comparator waveform issue (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl

My waveform does not change:

[image: my wave does not change]

I am working on my 32-bit comparator project. I already have an 1 bit one. I do not know where is the issue. Anyone can help me find that?

Thanks so much

Code:
1bit:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY comp1 is
port (a : IN std_logic ;
      b : IN std_logic ;
      g : IN std_logic ;
      l : IN std_logic ;
      e : IN std_logic ;
      great : OUT std_logic ;
      less : OUT std_logic ;
      equal : OUT std_logic );
END ;

ARCHITECTURE comp1_arch OF comp1 IS
signal s1,s2,s3: std_logic;
 begin
    s1 <= (a and (not b));
    s2  <= (not ((a and (not b)) or (b and (not a))));
    s3 <= (b and (not a));

    equal <= (e and s2) after 30 ns;
    great <= (g or(e and s1)) after 27 ns;
    less  <= (l or(e and s3)) after 27 ns;

end comp1_arch;
```

32 bit:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY comp32 is
GENERIC (BW : INTEGER :=32);
PORT ( a_32 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 DOWNTO 0);
       b_32 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 DOWNTO 0);
       g_32 : OUT STD_LOGIC ;
       l_32 : OUT STD_LOGIC ;
       e_32 : OUT STD_LOGIC );
END comp32;

ARCHITECTURE comp32_arch OF comp32 IS
  COMPONENT comp1
  PORT (a,b,g,l,e : IN std_logic ;
       great,less,equal : OUT std_logic);   
  END COMPONENT comp1;

  signal gre : std_logic_vector(BW downto 0);
  signal les : std_logic_vector(BW downto 0);
  signal equ : std_logic_vector(BW downto 0);

  begin
    gre(0)<='0';les(0)<='0';equ(0)<='0';
    gen: for i in 0 to BW-1 generate
        biti:   comp1 port map( a => a_32(i),b => b_32(i), g => gre(i), l => les(i), e =>equ(i), 
                                     great => gre(i+1), less => les(i+1),   equal => equ(i+1));
        end generate;
    g_32 <= gre(BW-1);
    l_32 <= les(BW-1);          
    e_32 <= equ(BW-1);

end comp32_arch;
```

Test Bench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY comp32_TB IS
END comp32_TB;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF comp32_TB IS 

COMPONENT comp32
PORT(
     a_32 : IN  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     b_32 : IN  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     g_32 : OUT  std_logic;
     l_32 : OUT  std_logic;
     e_32 : OUT  std_logic
    );
END COMPONENT;

signal a_32 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal b_32 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal g_32 : std_logic;
signal l_32 : std_logic;
signal e_32 : std_logic;

BEGIN

uut: comp32 PORT MAP (
      a_32 => a_32,
      b_32 => b_32,
      g_32 => g_32,
      l_32 => l_32,
      e_32 => e_32
    );

stim_proc: process
begin       
 a_32 <="00000000000000000000000000000000";b_32<="00000000000000000000000000000000";wait for 1500 ns;
  a_32 <="00000000000000000000000000000001";b_32<="00000000000000000000000000000000";wait for 1500 ns;    
  a_32 <="00000000000000000000000000000000";b_32<="10000000000000000000000000000000";wait for 1500 ns;
  wait;
end process;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had your chained signals backward, and the first inputs want to show equal:

```
architecture comp32_arch of comp32 is
  component comp1
  port (a,b,g,l,e : in std_logic ;
       great,less,equal : out std_logic);   
  end component comp1;

  signal gre : std_logic_vector(BW downto 0);
  signal les : std_logic_vector(BW downto 0);
  signal equ : std_logic_vector(BW downto 0);

  begin
      gre(BW) <= '0';   -- gre(0) <= '0';
      les(BW) <= '0';   -- les(0) <= '0';
      equ(BW) <= '1';   -- equ(0) <= '0';

  gen: 
      for i in 0 to BW-1 generate
  biti:
          comp1 
              port map ( 
                  a => a_32(i),
                  b => b_32(i),
                  g => gre(i+1),   -- gre(i),
                  l => les(i+1),   -- les(i), 
                  e => equ(i+1),   -- equ(i), 
                  great => gre(i), -- gre(i+1), 
                  less => les(i),  -- les(i+1), 
                  equal => equ(i)  -- equ(i+1)
              );
          end generate;
      g_32 <= gre(0);  -- gre(BW);-- (BW-1);
      l_32 <= les(0);  -- les(BW); -- (BW-1);          
      e_32 <= equ(0);  -- equ(BW); -- (BW-1);  
end architecture comp32_arch;
```

And that gives:

[image: comp32_tb_fixed.png]

The most significant bit without an equals defines either less than or greater than. If they're all equal that propagates all the way through.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!